# Find document by matching on [byte] array

Tags: c#, mongodb, byte

I have a collection in a MongoDB Database with two fields; the first field is _id with ObjectID datatype, and the second is Bytes with byte[] datatype:

```json
public class ImageItem {
    public ObjectID _id;
    public byte[] Bytes;
}
```

The question is: coding in C#, how can I get a document from this collection by matching Bytes ? That is to say, how to get a single document using a single parameter (Bytes), or check if such a document exists?